# Nodejs MetaAPI Cloud / Calculate moving average

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, trading, moving-average

im making a trading bot who uses metaapi.cloud, I am trying to calculate the moving average (fast/exponential) but it returns me invalid values, here is my code :

```js
async movingAverage(symbol, period, type = "S") {
        let candles = (await this.account.getHistoricalCandles(symbol, this.params.timeframe, null, period)).map(c => c.close);
        const result = [];
        let sum = 0;
        if (type === "S") {
            for (let i = 0; i < period; i++) {
                sum += candles[i];
            }
            result.push(sum / period);
            for (let i = period; i < candles.length; i++) {
                sum = sum - candles[i - period] + candles[i];
                result.push(sum / period)
            }
        } else if (type === "E") {
            const weight = 2 / (period + 1);
            for (let i = 0; i < period; i++) {
                sum += candles[i];
            }
            sum /= period;
            result.push(sum);

            for (let i = period; i < candles.length; i++) {
                sum = (candles[i] * weight) + (sum * (1 - weight));
                result.push(sum);
            }
        } else {
            // throw Error()
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Here is how I use it :

```js
async onTick(infos) {
        let sma = await this.movingAverage(infos.symbol, this.params.fast, "S");
        console.log('SMA ' + sma[0]);
}
```

Right now when I test it, the SMA should return "1906.6963", but it gives me "1900.7813"
Maybe im using the wrong way to calculate them?
If someone has a solution! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It come from the api of MetaTrader, the "getHistoricalCandles" dont work correctly as expected.
In the api its written :

```
getHistoricalCandles(symbol, timeframe, startTime, limit)
symbol: symbol to retrieve candles for
TimeFrame: define the timeframe according to which the candles must be generated
StartTime: time to start loading candles from. Note that candles are loaded in backward direction, so this should be the latest time, **leave it empty to request latest candles**
Limit: maximum of candles to retrieve, must be less or equals to 1000
```

The problem here is the StartTime parameter, it absolutely dont work like they said, when I leave it empty, or when I put a `Date.now()` it retrieve candles from 5 hours before, and to retrieve the absolute last candle, I have to put `Date.now()+10000000000`, so this might be a timezone error, unsolvable for the moment cause its from api side...

Comment: Depending on your account settings you might have misconfigured account timezone in MetaApi for your account or broker. There is currently no any known bug regarding timezone conversion.

Answer (score 0):

- SMA looks correct, EMA has many different modes. Since you did not post an example dataset, it is hard to guess what is passed from the server, but there can be a lot of values that cannot be converted such as NaN, null, empty string or numbers with commas, exponentials etc. I just replaced candles with an array with faulty values. Do some filtering and then do the calculation
- Take into consideration if period > dataset. In that case, set period to length.

In the below example, set period to 1  to see all the values that are processed, set period a very large number to see the entire average.

There must be other edge cases that I didn't think of. For brevity the below example uses SMA.

```js
async function movingAverage(symbol, period, type = "S") {
        let candles = [1,2,3,"","",4, "0",0, null, "99,9123", undefined,"0.123e5", "wrongval", 9, 10, 20, 100]
        .map(d => parseFloat((d ?? "").toString().replace(",",".")))
        .filter(d => +d || +d === 0);
        const result = [];
        if (candles.length <= 0){return result}
        let sum = 0;
        period = Math.min(candles.length, period) || 1;
        for (let i = 0; i < period; i++) {
            sum += candles[i];
        }
        result.push(sum / period);
        for (let i = period; i < candles.length; i++) {
            sum = sum - candles[i - period] + candles[i];
            result.push(sum / period)
        }
        return result;
    }
    movingAverage("SPX",500).then(x => document.getElementById("result").textContent = x)
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: The dataset is a large array of last bitcoin closing price, like 29985.545,29962.478 etc etc..  I already checked both length and they are equals

Comment: Paste it and test it with the function above and let me know if you still get the wrong number

Comment: Yes and on ETHUSD it gives a huge difference, the correct number is 1968 and it gives me 1909